# C# OleDBConnection connecting to previous IP?

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

I have multiple databases (30+) that are used at clinics and setup automatically via the license software they use. So each database is named the same and use the same port, the only thing that changes is the IP. That being said, I am using the following code to attempt to run a query against them individually. However, when I change out the IP and run the script again it is returning the results from the previous server.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConnectionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(host=X.X.X.X,PORT=2638);ServerName=EAGLESOFT;Integrated Security = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tran_num, provider_id, tran_date FROM transactions WHERE tran_date LIKE '2015-11-23%'", conn))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}", reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception connerr) { Debug.WriteLine(connerr.Message); }
                conn.Close();
            }
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try the DoBroadcast option in your tcpip options like: CommLinks=tcpip{DoBroadcast=Direct;Host=10.100.104.35;Port=2640}

Comment: Yeah I found the the same thing, this did the trick. Set it to `DoBroadcast=None;` and it forced the command to connect to the specified IP. I appreciate all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you would be getting previous results, here.  Are you running multiple instances of this code at the same time?  Are you manually changing the IP address in your code each time? I assume the "Transactions" object is an actual table and not something being generated on-the-fly?

With just a tiny bit of modification, you could pass the IP address as a command line parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ip, port = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i].StartsWith("/i:"))
            ip = args[i].Substring(args[i].IndexOf(':') + 1);
        else if (args[i].StartsWith("/p:"))
            port = args[i].Substring(args[i].IndexOf(':') + 1);
    }

    // Default the port value to 2638 (since I have no idea if that changes).
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
        port = "2638";

    string connStr = string.Format("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(host={0},PORT={1});ServerName=EAGLESOFT;Integrated Security = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql", ip, port);
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                // You could also implement a WHILE loop with a small delay (~1200ms) and try again to open the connection, with a counter to "fail" after a certain number (like 3) of attempts.
                throw new Exception("Unable to open connection to database.");

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tran_num, provider_id, tran_date FROM transactions WHERE tran_date LIKE '2015-11-23%'", conn))
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}", reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception connerr)
        { Debug.WriteLine(connerr.Message); }
        finally
        { conn.Close(); }
    }
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are all great suggestions, I'll attempt to see if anything changes with them added.

I'm only running this as a single instance and manually changing out the IPs to test the connections. The `transactions` is a table, yes. The port never changes, as I stated all these are setup with default values by the software each clinic is using. The only thing that is different is the IP itself on the network.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Let us know what you find out.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost (for testing purposes, that is) I would probably try removing the `ServerName` parameter since you're already providing an IP address explicitly.

So your connection string would be:

```
Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(host=X.X.X.X,PORT=2638);Integrated Security = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql
```

Similar to ORA files, DSNs, etc, it almost sounds like you have a server alias configured for `EAGLESOFT` that may be overwriting the IP preference in your testing.

Comment: I agree with the overwriting reference, however LINKS throws an error without ServerName

Comment: Admittedly, I've never worked with Sybase, but have you tried passing the IP address to the ServerName or Server parameter? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh302792(v=sql.110).aspx) seems to suggest it might be "valid" (Sybase 15 parameter) but again I've never worked with their connection strings before.

Comment: Yeah, Sybase isn't my first choice and is what this hoping to solve by consolidating all of these DBs into a single SQL 2014 Server. But yes, I have tried ServerNamme=X.X.X.X and ServerName=X.X.X.X:2638 with it resulting in no return.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark (taken from [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/host-network-conparm.html), but what about `links=tcpip(HOST=x.x.x.x:1234)` as opposed to `links=tcpip(HOST=x.x.x.x,port=1234)`. The `VerifyServerName=no` parameter also looks interesting. Short of actually spinning up a Sybase installation myself, I think I'm at a lost at this point :P

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help! I'll give those a try

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change EagleSoft as well as IP.  You have to pass the IP address as an arg[].  Modify code as below to allow the IP to change

```
           string host = "X.X.X.X";
            string conStr = string.Format("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(host={0},PORT=2638);ServerName=EAGLESOFT;Integrated Security = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql", host);
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
 ​
```

Comment: I've added this without any changes to my results

Comment: You are still using EagleSoft which is always getting you the same server.  Replace EagleSoft with {0}

Comment: Because every instance is going to be EAGLESOFT. Unless I'm missing something, changing it to an arg that is static won't change any results.

Comment: Each Server usually has its own IP.

Comment: Yes, which I stated I manually changed the IP when I attempt to run the script again. But you keep mentioning EAGLESOFT, which I understand is the ServerName in this statement, but it is always labeled EAGLESOFT regardless of which IP I am going to. As mentioned above, I have already attempted changing EAGLESOFT to an IP which results in no return due to "Database server not found"

Comment: No.  Each IP will have a different Server Name.  You can use IP instead of Server name.  So try this :         string conStr = string.Format("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(host={0},PORT=2638);ServerName={0};Integrated Security = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql", host);